# PNG not shown in IE6

Tags: html, internet-explorer-6, png

When I open a specific png file in IE6, it just displays a red X, which looks like image not found error. It works fine in other browsers. Some other png images can render correct in IE6. I checked the can-render png with can-not-render png with fiddler, I found the can-not-render png is only 150 bytes. I wonder if the too small size causes the problem.

Update:

Finally, after communicating with the guys providing these png files, they told me that it is png compression issue. If you compress png file much more, it may break in ie6 sometimes. So the workaround is to sacrifice size of png file during compression, and it does work.

Anyway thank guys in stackoverflow as well :)

Comment: What are you trying to do with this PNG, and what program/output settings did you use to create the file?

Comment: I had the same problem with a jpg yesterday, it was a cmyk image rather than rgb, which IE can't render. Try resaving it and check the settings. A link might be useful as well.

Comment: @Gabriel, I just want to show it. The PNG is dynamically generated.
@Rich, I will check it. It's for internal usage.

Comment: If you share out the PNG somewhere public, I can help you find out why it fails.

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/) can help you to fix a known problem about PNG and IE6. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

Belatedpng is the best png fix for ie6 that I have found:

http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/

Comment: Many thanks. I tried so many things, but this was the only thing that worked.

Answer (score 0):

IE6 is known for it's problems with PNG files.

If I were you I would change it to JPG or GIF.

Regards.

Comment: Yes, I had problems with transparencies in IE6, but there are people claiming that gAMA chunks don't work too (I haven't tested it). Anyhow I would replace all the PNG files for IE6. + info: http://hsivonen.iki.fi/png-gamma/